# How to get posts in Wordpress by tags using Timber guery parameters

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

In `wordpress.call`, I received an empty answer for a certain tag id. What is correct lists of parameters to get posts connected with a specified tag?

```
{% set present_cat_id = '18' %}

{% set query_parameters = {
    'post_status' : 'publish',
    'posts_per_page': limit.total|default('-1'),
    'cat': present_cat_id,
    'offset': limit.start|default('0'),
    'orderby': sort.orderby,
    'order': sort.ordering,
    'ignore_sticky_posts': sticky_posts,
    'post__in': filter.posts ? filter.posts|split(',') : '',
} %}

{% set articles = wordpress.call('Timber::get_posts', query_parameters) %}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you do everything in Twig? Are you using a special or framework, or do you have access to the PHP template files? Because usually, you would define your queries in PHP, and then pass the result of the query to your Twig file. And where do all your variables liek `limit`, `sort` or `filter` come from. Also, do you want to query post tags or categories? Because now, you seem to be querying a certain category.

Comment: What is `wordpress.call`? Never seen it in Timber document before. Could you provide a link of it document?